# create Alarmservice in application

Tags: android

I am newbie to android and just can do small simple tasks with android. Now i am trying to learn a bit harder things.
I want to build an application just like to-do task manager. In which i want to include  feature of setting reminder for every particular task, the rest i would be able to handle. Can anyone please guide me or provide me tutorial for setting reminder. I think this includes a background service which constantly monitors the time and date, for a particular event to occur, and when that time and date matches to the task in the application it popups a reminder. Also, this service should start automatically even after restarting the phone. Please someone can guide me through if my direction of thinking is somewhat correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [AlarmManager and BroadCastReceiver](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html) that receives your alarm.

> Note: The Alarm Manager is intended for cases where you want to have your application code run at a specific time, even if your application is not currently running.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll surely start my work on this today itself. And, yes ofcourse, your "Note" resembles my need in the application. Thank you for guiding me... And shall i ask you one thing...??? Is my direction about making this app correct to some extent ?? please reply and/or comment to this...